# Custom Post Type URL doesn't work anymore

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Suddenly one of my custom post types stopped working properly. More precisely, I have a custom post type called Apps where I have a few posts. Everything was working properly until I've created a new taxonomy using a plugin, then I've imported about 2-300 terms using an array in `functions.php` and then I've created a custom template for that taxonomy. Right after, the Apps posts couldn't be accessed anymore - even if nothing changed to them, the URL doesn't work, I get a Page Not Found error.

I reverted back to the original settings - delete the new taxonomy and terms, disable plugin, but I still get a 'page not found' error when I try to access the Apps posts.

You can see the behavior on this [website](http://kiddoware.com/apps/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to update your Permalink Settings? That might sort it out. Btw. how did you named your CPT?

Comment: I did update the Permalinks but at the time it didn't work. Following your advice I thought about changing the permalink structure and apparently that worked. Then I switched back the permalinks to the original setting and everything works fine. Now, I'll try to include my custom taxonomy again (which is named parentalcontrol - unique name so that it doesn't interfere with anything else).

Comment: I'm glad it helped